# How to replace a tag using jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I want to replace all image tags with `div` tag. I am able to select all tags and I know that I have to use `replaceWith`. But I am unable to use it.

And if I use `TextNode` for replacing it with `<div> </div>` and it converts into `&amp;lt;div&amp;gt; my div &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;`

I know `&amp;lt;` and `&amp;gt;` is for `<` and `>`

Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you are replacing with `element.replaceWith(new TextNode("<div></div>"),"");`?

A `Textnode` is for text and escapes content - thats why you see the HTML entities. You need to replace with a tag, so do something like `element.replaceWith(new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), ""));`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am also able to do it with DataNode

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way of achieving this:

```
 Elements elements= doc.getElementsByTag("img");
 elements.tagName("div");
```

Hope that is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

just use find method and pass specific tags
`let tag = soup.find('tag_name') tag.name = 'new_tag';//replaced tag`

for multiple tag just put inside loop
`let tag = soup.findAll('tag_name'); if (tag) { for (let i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) { tag[i].name = 'your_new_tag'; } }`