# Replacing tag with letters using JSoup

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

Hello I have tried these answers: [How to replace a tag using jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008969/how-to-replace-a-tag-using-jsoup) and [Replace HTML tags using jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475213/replace-html-tags-using-jsoup) to my case unsuccessfully. I am parsing a website with JSoup and I ran accross letter-look GIF images. Fortunately those gif images have a specific name, e.g. a.gif for letter "A".

HTML input:

```
<body>
  <p><img src="http://www.example.com/images/a.gif" align="left">mong us!</p>
</body>
```

Desired output:

```
<body>
  <p>Among us!</p>
</body>
```

My java code (below) does not print the expected output:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
if(document.select("img").attr("src").contains("a.gif"))
  {
    document.select("img").get(0).replaceWith(new Element(Tag.valueOf("img"), "A"));
  }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `TextNode` instead of `Element`.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
if (document.select("img").get(0).attr("src").contains("a.gif")) {
    document.select("img").get(0).replaceWith(new TextNode("A", ""));
    System.out.println(document);
}
```

The above code can print html as you expected.

Comment: Thank you, it works with a minor addition, if I add in the IF statement .get(0); `if(document.select("img").get(0).attr("src").contains("a.gif"))`

Comment: @Rodo Yep, I missed the `.get(0)` in my `IF` statement. I will correct it in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonCao I want to replace the path of the image. So I am saving the image locally and displaying it from the local path instead of the path on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Try this!!

```
  Elements elements = doc.select("img[src$=a.gif]");
   for(Element element : elements)
    {
      element.replaceWith(new TextNode("A", null));
    }
```

Comment: It works, but I needed a IF statement hint since I can run across different letters. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Niranjan! Looks like this is only way to do this. `A` would be `element.text()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This:**

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
    if(document.select("img").attr("src").contains("a.gif"))
      {
       String result ="";
       String src =document.select("img").attr("src").text();
       result = src.replace(src,"A");
       System.out.println(result);

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
if (document.select("img").get(0).attr("src").contains("a.gif")) {
    document.select("img").get(0).replaceWith(new TextNode("A", null));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works as desired if I add in IF statement .get(0); `if(document.select("img").get(0).attr("src").contains("a.gif"))`

Comment: @AliHashemi, thank you! I was looking for this solution, because before I did not understand very well how to manipulate the elements of html in java.