# Replace open and close tag?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a html/xml file in which in need to replace specific tags. I'm running into trouble with the following xml:

```
<section>
    <banner>
</section>
```

I can replace the `<banner>` tag with solutions like:
[Replacing tag with letters using JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346962/replacing-tag-with-letters-using-jsoup)

But I'm running into trouble with tags that have children, for example:
replace `<section>` with `<mysection><b>` and `</section>` with `</b></mysection>`?

(of course keeping the children of the `<section>` tag)

I tried:

```
els = doc.select("section");
els.tagName("mysection");
```

but i also want the `<b>` tag to be added (and a bit more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
// sample data: a parent section containing nodes
String szHTML = "<section><banner><child>1</child></banner><abc></abc></section>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(szHTML);

// select the element section
Element sectionEle = doc.select("section").first();

// renaming the section element to mysection
sectionEle.tagName("mysection");

// get all the children elements of section element
Elements children = sectionEle.children();

// remove all the children
for(Node child: children){
    child.remove();
}

// insert element b in mysection
Element b = sectionEle.appendElement("b");

// insert all the child nodes back to element b
b.insertChildren(0, children);


System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Desired output:

```
  <mysection>
   <b>
    <banner>
     <child>
      1
     </child>
    </banner>
    <abc></abc></b>
  </mysection>
```

Comment: Thumbs up Sandeep! This works like a charm, nice find on the insertChildren one.